# I need to create a horizontal list from a vertical list of 500 words for a function

Tags: php, list

I'm creating a 'bad words' filter as str_ireplace function and I have a list of about 500 bad words.. all in a long vertical list.  Any idea how I could quickly and easily create a horizontal, comma-delimited formatted list without manually typing a comma after every word and backspacing?

And yes..  I could probably do this in 20 minutes, but I've had this problem before so I'm asking for all the future times I run into this too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use find and replace. If whatever editor you're using for your coding can't cope with finding carriage returns try Word, Notepad++, etc.

Comment: that might take care of the comma problem, but not creating a horizontal list. I'm playing with Excel now.. got to be some way to do this.

Comment: @Andi - Maybe you should update your question with a short sample (say, five words) of before and after, so we can see what your desired output is. I assumed you just wanted `"apple,bee,caramel,dragon,etc"`. If you want `"'apple','bee','etc'"` or some other similar variation that'd be just as easy with find and replace...

Answer (score 0):

In php it would be something like:

```
str_replace(array("\r", "\r\n", "\n"), ", ", $string);
```

Or

```
$file = file("list.txt");
print_r($file);
```

Or, if you want to use bash for that, this would be the thing:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n/, /;ta' list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents('filename', implode(',', file('filename', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)));
```

This code rewrite your file exactly as you want